# How to register my maven archetype so that it gets listed as part of archetype:generate

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

How to register my maven archetype so that it gets listed as part of **mvn archetype:generate** call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `mvn archetype:generate` command lists the archetype defined in the catalog file from the maven central repository...

This catalog is meant to contains stable and reliable archetypes...

If your archetype will help us to save the world, you should create a JIRA and ask for them to register you project: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Otherwise you can setup a local catalog that will be used to spread your project.

HIH
M.

Answer (score 0):

you can install the archtype ( mvn install) into your local repository first and then it will be available for mvn archetype:generate command.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=gpid  -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype
```